# Getting two objects based on success or error Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

The service I am calling using my Spring Boot application returns two different object type depending upon Http GET request success or exception. When success it returns "MyClass" object and when there is an exception the it returns "ErrorResponse" object. I wanted to know that if it is the right way, the way I implemented it.

```
public class MyClass{

public ErrorResponse errorResponse;

//and some other fields here
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class ErrorResponse {
    @JsonProperty("error")
    public Error error;

      @JsonProperty("version") 
      public String version;

}

public class Error {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String Code;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String Message;
}
```

The way error response I get is

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidEntry",
        "message": "The request you are making is invalid, please check your request data"
    },
    "version": "2.1.1"
}
```

And my implementation is as follows:

```
HttpEntity<MyClass> entity = new HttpEntity<MyClass>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<MyClass> response = new ResponseEntity<MyClass>(HttpStatus.OK);

        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyClass.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            String responseBody = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 

            try {
                ErrorResponse errorResponse = mapper.readValue(responseBody, ErrorResponse.class);
                MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
                myClass.errorResponse = errorResponse;
                return myClass;
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

return response.getBody();
```

Comment: For this `I wanted to know that if it is the right way, the way I implemented it` yes  but you can use https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code but it seems regardless if there is an exception or not, you are returning "MyClass" object.

On Exception:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.errorResponse = errorResponse;
return myClass;
```

To answer your question, NO, it is not the right way of implementing it.